# Old pc game featuring a pirate

Tags: story-identification, video-games

A game from around 2012 or older where the player controlling a bulky-old pirate in 3rd person. The graphic is not cartoonish. I think its similar with RE 4. In the early gameplay the pirate is inside some kind of maze room(?) in the middle of island or forest. The player need to get out by climbing platform and solving puzzle one of which involving using a cannon to break a cell. I remember the pirate has a sword and a gun but i don't remember there is any enemy to fight. Also, the pirate has an ability to transorm into demonic form with similar characteristic as the dark prince in Prince of Persia game. I never passed the first stage/level so i don't know anything more.

Comment: God mode? One of your early skins is that of a pirate; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6p1Wrpcr8mo